# From a box of $30$ balls ($5$ in each of $6$ colours), we draw $5$ balls. How many combinations are there about the colours of $5$ balls?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I recently came across this problem in a math competition and I have written a proof for this. However, I am not really sure if my proof is rigorous or even correct at all. That's why I am here since I need help to verify if it is correct and if I did not assume anything without proving it.

Here is the problem:

> There are $30$ balls in a box. The balls are in $6$ colours. For each colour, there are $5$ balls. If we draw $5$ balls randomly and simultaneously, how many combinations are there about the colours of $5$ balls?

This is my solution:

[image]

Comment: Hi there. You will have better luck if you type up your proof here instead of linking to a handwritten proof.

Comment: $\binom{10}5$ by stars and bars is correct.

Comment: It amazes me the amount of pointless garbage gets put into the description of some of these problems. I suppose the purpose of doing so is to train the student into being able to spot what is significant, and what is unnecessary. In the case, the whole problem boils down to "how many ways can you color five balls with six colors?"